# How to discover Roku device from within an Android app in order to cast

Tags: android, casting, roku

I am developing an app that has some video content that can be cast over WiFi to other devices (like smart TV).

The logic for casting to smart TV, Android TV, or Google Chromecast has been implemented and it works.

There is the same app for Roku and it is installed on my Roku device but the android app cannot discover this Roku device at all. It just lists smart TV, but no Roku device.

I checked several posts and it seems to me like Play Services Cast library won't work with Roku.

Those are the casting dependencies that I am using in the android app:

```
implementation "androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:16.1.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:16.1.2"
```

Does anyone here have some experience with casting from within the android app to Roku?
Is there a Roku SDK for android that makes Roku visible for casting on Android devices?
Maybe this same app on the Roku device must implement some logic in order to be discoverable for the same app on android?
How can this be done?

I see YouTube has this feature, Netflix & Spotify as well, so I guess it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is possible on Roku devices through DIAL (Discovery and Launch). Unlike other platforms one don't need to register in DIAL registry for Roku devices. If you want Roku app to be discoverable from other devices, there should be following entry in roku app manifest file -

```
dial_title="dial_service_name"
```

Although Roku has equivalent implementation called ECP, but they support DIAL as it is widely accepted and cross domain solution for casting. You can find more detailed information [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md). You can download sample application from following link --

https://github.com/rokudev/samples/blob/master/utilities/RokuDIALSDK.zip